# « Deux pages recto-verso » : comment l'interpréter ?

Tags: sens, usage

Lorsqu'on demande pour un devoir de rendre « 2 pages recto-verso » cela signifie-t-il :

- Deux feuilles écrites au recto et au verso, soit au total l'équivalent de 4 pages écrites uniquement au recto.
- Une seule feuille de papier mais dont le recto et le verso sont tout les deux remplis. Soit au total l'équivalent de 2 pages écrites uniquement au recto.

?

Comment: Parler de deux pages recto-verso exprime une confusion entre la page et la feuille. Une feuille de papier a deux pages (deux faces). C'est une feuille qui peut être utilisée recto-verso.  C'est à dire qu'une feuille écrite recto-verso  est écrite sur ses deux pages / deux faces.

Comment: @Laure : Oui tu as bien mis en évidence où se situait la confusion. Mais est-ce que qu'une personne qui demande `deux pages recto-verso` s'attend à recevoir deux feuilles recto-verso ou bien une seule ? :/

Comment: Elle a fait une erreur et il faut lui poser la question. Sinon tu ne peux qu'interpréter. Sur un forum de français on ne peut que te donner une réponse sur le sens des mots et pas des conseils de relations humaines !

Comment: Une interprétation probable (mais elle vaut ce qu'elle vaut, ce n'est pas scientifique) c'est qu'elle voulait dire de rendre « deux pages, soit une feuille recto-verso » mais que la fatigue lui a fait avaler une partie de la phrase.

Comment: @Laure: Perso, j'aurais tendance à penser que la personne pensait à deux feuilles.

Comment: Si on prend comme référence la numérotation des pages d'un livre ça serait donc plutôt l’interprétation que tu en fais Laure qui est correcte. Mais si j'ai posé cette question c'est que de façon intuitive j'ai plutôt tendance à répondre comme @StéphaneGimenez.

Comment: @Fractaliste j'ai amélioré ma réponse, et indiqué ce que je ferais si on me demandait de faire un devoir "deux pages recto-verso", en effet, pour un professeur avoir une réponse sur deux feuilles amène le risque de mélanger différentes réponses. S'il exigeait deux feuilles, il aurait demandé une **feuille de copie double**

Comment: @cl-r: ne t'avance pas trop sur les intentions ou les interprétations des profs...

Answer (score 7):

- *Feuille* : feuille physique de papier sur laquelle une impression peut être effectuée,
- *Recto* : face que l'on a devant les yeux,
- *Verso* : face non visible de la feuille,
- *Page* : double sens

  - soit *recto* ou *verso*,
  - soit partie d'un document cohérent que l'on met au format d'une page, mais qui peut être imprimé dans un autre format que celui de la feuille.

*Tel que je comprends la question :*

1) Dans le cadre des économies de papier dans une entreprise, un rapport sera mis en page à raison de deux pages de document sur le recto et deux autres pages de document sur verso.

2) Dans le cadre d'un devoir, cela signifie répondre en deux pages (maximum) sur une seule feuille de papier, et donc ne pas utiliser deux feuilles (sinon il est demandé *une feuille de copie double*), mais le recto et le verso d'une seule.

Comment: Le sens des mots *feuille* et *page* n'est pas différent dans le domaine scolaire et le domaine de l'entreprise.

Comment: @Laure mais je n'en ai pas mis! J'ai seulement détaillé le support [feuille] en recto et en verso dans le 1) et utilisé son nom dans le 2).

Comment: 1) Tu attribues à la page la définition de la feuille (un recto-verso). 2) Tu donne au mot feuille son sens propre (une feuille a deux pages).

Comment: @Laure Euréka : "La page de document" (le contenu que l'on peut mettre dans un format A4 et que l'on rétrécit en A5) n'est pas la page recto de la feuille physique [A4] (alors que dans la question il y a confusion de terme ... enfin me semble-t-il )

Comment: Après avoir relu 4 fois, j'ai enfin compris ce que tu voulais dire dans le premier point. Le verbe n'est pas *éditer* mais *mettre en page*, ou *imprimer*… et, ça n'a aucun lien direct avec le schmilblick. Une réponse à cette question se doit de mentionner l'ambiguïté de la formulation. « Deux pages, une recto, une verso » ou « Deux feuilles recto-verso » sont parfaitement compréhensibles, mais « deux pages recto-verso » c'est un mélange douteux.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Précisions apportées ; j'ai fait un choix d'interprétation tel que mes souvenirs me le suggèrent ; je reste disponible pour tout autre point de vue.

Answer (score 6):

Une feuille a deux pages, donc *2 pages*, c'est une feuille.

*recto-verso* donne une indication sur la disposition de ces deux pages: une page sur le recto, l'autre sur le verso (implicitement de la même feuille).

Answer (score 2):

"*[Écrire] Deux pages recto-verso*" signifie écrire au recto **ainsi qu'**au verso de chaque page, soit deux feuilles où l'on écrit des deux côtés de chacune d'entre elles.

Cela représente la même quantité d'écritures que quatre feuilles où l'on n'aurait écrit qu'au recto (ou bien au verso mais pas les deux). Dans ce cas là on parle de "*quatre feuilles recto*".

Answer (score 0):

Lorsqu'on demande pour un devoir de rendre « 2 pages recto-verso » cela signifie que si tu ne comprends pas il faut poser la question à la personne concernée.

Personne ici ne pourra te répondre correctement dû à la confusion probable entre feuille et page.
En effet, si c'est bien "page" il faudra donc écrire sur les deux cotés (recto-verso) d'une feuille simple ce qui nous donnera 2 pages, mais si c'est le terme "feuille" qui était pensé, alors il faudra écrire l'équivalent de 4 pages sur deux feuilles.